# Drupal 7 Workbench: node title/type/date info missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site which uses the Workbench module to view revisions. Some nodes in the list are all blank except for the author and option to delete the node. Again, it is just a few that are these "phantom" nodes, and they are all at the bottom of the list (after the least recent draft).

This is the view for the site administrator. For other collaborators, they simply do not see those nodes on their Workbench tabs.

When viewing content under "Content” rather than Workbench everything displays fine.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Views UI installed? Go in and check and the fields for the particular Workbench view you're having a problem with.